# Huawei Mobile Services IAP Unable to make purchases -5 Core Error

Tags: huawei-mobile-services

I have integrated HMS IAP, these are the dependencies:

```
classpath 'com.huawei.agconnect:agcp:1.2.1.301'

huaweiImplementation 'com.huawei.hms:ads-identifier:3.4.32.300'
huaweiImplementation 'com.huawei.hms:ads-lite:13.4.32.300'
huaweiImplementation 'com.huawei.hms:iap:5.0.1.300'
huaweiImplementation 'com.huawei.hms:hwid:4.0.4.300'
```

I have also downloaded and added agconnect-services.json

When I launch my app, I don't see my IAP products and my logcat shows:

`2020-09-24 15:08:30 15575-15575/? V/UpgradePurchase: Unable to make purchases: -5: Core error`

This is the check to see if the device isEnvReady, I do not see documentation with that error code. Can anyone let me know what -5 stands for? What should I change in my project?

Thank you.

Comment: What phone model are you testing in? Can you check what is HMS Core version in your phone?

Comment: I use P40 Pro (ELS-NX9), EMUI 10.1.0.158, HMS Core 5.0.2.301. Thank you.

Comment: Did you check with isEnvReady if the IAP services are available?

Comment: isEnvReady is not ready in my case.

Comment: That means IAP is currently not available in your region.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is an issue with United States HUAWEI ID issue. I received official support that IAP is not supported in US. I changed my phone settings > login using a HAUWEI ID from a country that supports HMS IAP (like Germany) and I was able to see IAP interface.